# В(на) титульном листе

Tags: лексика

"Допустив ошибку в(на) титульном листе, бланк необходимо уничтожить"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы пишем **на листе**, и ошибки допускаем там же. Поэтому - "Допустив ошибку  **на** титульном **листе**, бланк необходимо уничтожить"

Answer (score 1):

Из-за того, что между деепричастным оборотом и инфинитивом вклинивается слово "бланк", фраза приобретает вид полного предложения, т.е. классического варианта "проезжая мимо станции". Думаю, если бы было написано "Допустив ошибку на листе, необходимо уничтожить бланк", предложение выглядело более корректным.

Comment: Но она, имхо, лучше не становится.

Comment: По-моему, нет отличий в фразах "Допустив ошибку на титульном листе, бланк необходимо уничтожить" и "Допустив ошибку на листе, необходимо уничтожить бланк" :)

Comment: behemothus: Согласна.

Liana: Формально нет, конечно. Чуть более похожа на приведенный Ларf пример из Розенталя. Попытка паллиативного решения, раз уж я не смогла найти точного обоснования корявости фразы. ))

Answer (score 0):

**Допустив подобную ошибку вам уже ничего не поможет**.

Какой, к черту, титульный лист, если у вас деепричастный оборот от субъекта оторван? ;)
Ларf, простите, но вы-то хоть таких советов не давайте. У нас на то Остер есть со своми книжками.

~~~~ 
*В случае ошибки НА/В титульном листе, бланк подлежит уничтожению* - как-то так.
НА - если речь идет о физическом бумажном носителе, 
В - если только о текте. 
Но поскольку речь идет о бланке, второй вариант, видимо, неактуален.

Comment: Мне тоже не очень нравится такое предложение.  Но! Стало допустимым употребление деепричастных оборотов в безличных инфинитивных предложениях. Этот случай постоянно встречается в тестовой части ЕГЭ по русскому языку.

Comment: Возможно, мы по-разному прочитали предложение. Если ошибку допустил и лист уничтожать будет один субъект - такое предложение верно. Если ситуация предполагает разных субъектов, то это. конечно, ошибка.

Comment: Не видиел, что там в ЕГЭ, но по грамматике что-то подобное допускается (с оговорками), когда субъект (производитель действия) совпадает у сказуемого и деепричастия. Здесь же мешает слово "необходимо" вообще исключаеющее субъект.
Если есть примеры из ЕГЭ на что-то подобное приведенному здесь примеру, прошу покорно обнародовать. Может я совсем от эжизни отстал...

Comment: Подумал, я, может, и правда чего-то недопонимаю.
А что с грамматикой этого предложения по ЕГЭ?
Сказуемое - предикатив "необходимо" или уже опять что-то променялось? И относится ли к безличным предложение со сказуемым-преликативом иперативного толка (нада, нкжно, необходимо)? У Розенталя и проих авторитетов - примеры безличных все больше на "приходилось", "требовалось" и т.д.

Comment: Редактируя рукопись, нужно учитывать... - из Розенталя. Предложения безличные. На ЕГЭ как верные. "Необходимо уничтожить" - главный член предложения. Ничего не поменялось. Всегда так было.

Comment: Не вижу такого.
Аналогичные куски и в лругих изданиях.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действие подлежащего: 
   1) если производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, совпадает с производителем действия, обозначенного другой глагольной формой, например: Автору было предложено внести в рукопись дополнения, учитывая последние достижения науки в данной области; Ничем нельзя было удержать напора волн, нахлынувших на берег, сметая всё на своём пути;

Comment: 2) в безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например: Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха. Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно, например: «Уезжая из родного города, мне стало грустно»; «Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что она нуждается в серьезной доработке»;

Comment: 3) в обороте со словами исходя из, образующем особую конструкцию без значения добавочного действия, например: Расчёт составляется исходя из средних норм выработки. 
   Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия, выраженного глаголом-сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают, например: «Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана».

Comment: <<"Необходимо уничтожить" - главный член предложения. Ничего не поменялось. Всегда так было.>>  
На ЕГЭ, не щнаю, а вообще "всегда" - это от силы псоледние лет двадцать. До этого и понятия "главный член односоставного предложения" не было.  
Ну да ладно, тут другое важнее.  
**Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно** (Р-ль). Так вот, "допустив ошибку" тут относится к "необходимо", а не к единственному инфинитиву "уничтожить". Поэтому фраза такой гобатой и выглядит.

Comment: Впрочем, вынужден признать, что "стилистически неоправданно" не знасит "грамматически ошибочно". Хотя мне по-прежнему кажется, что это именно грамматическая ошибка. Против "нафдя обишубку, необходимо уничтожить", я, пожадуй, после всех наших разговоров уже юы не возражал. Но исходное предложение - чудовищно.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, не совсем по теме, но не могу не придраться к предложению: "В случае ошибки НА/В титульном листе, бланк подлежит уничтожению". По-моему, здесь запятая не нужна!